# Getting Google analytics working with Pelican

Tags: google-analytics, pelican

So I recently started blogging with Pelican, and everything is going great with the exception of Google Analytics. I publish my blog using the

```
make s3_upload
```

command, which uses the publishconf.py file.

To get my Tracking ID, all I did was copy paste my Tracking ID from the google analytics page into the Google Analytics line in the publishconf.py file, like so

```
# Following items are often useful when publishing

#DISQUS_SITENAME = ""
GOOGLE_ANALYTICS = "UA-########-#"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been racking my brain trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that the Google Analytics tracking snippet is present in the HTML that Pelican renders? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: That's it, it's not in any of the output created. I looked in the templates, and nothing was in there either. As I can see it, two options are to add it to the theme, or switch themes. Thanks for the help! I knew it was something silly.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have the `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS` variable defined but the snippet is missing from the output

Comment: works for me. maybe they fixed it.

Comment: It worked for me by just adding the value for `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS `

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

1. editing publishconf.py

   GOOGLE_ANALYTICS = "UA-########-#"
2. Building the website

   pelican content
3. Modifying the website according to settings = adding google analytics

   pelican -s publishconf.py  .
4. Deploying

   cd output && git push origin master

**Tests** that the steps work:

3. Locally at the end of output/index.html it added:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-125105451-1', 'auto');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
   </script>
   ```
4. Check that the javascript code has been addded to your github repo. Check that the code is serve in a " private navigation " ( in order to disable browser caching). Right click on your webpage > see source.

**Context**: Deployment to github pages

Git for the blog:

```
cd output/ 
git init .
git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/<username>.github.io.git
# Deploy with:
# git add . && git commit -m "Commit description" && git push origin master
```

Git for the blog engine:

```
cd output && cd .. # ensure to be in the good repository
git init .
git submodule add git@github.com:<username>/<username>.github.io.git output/
```

Answer (score 2):

If the Analytics snippet is not in the output for your site, it's likely the theme you're using didn't include the proper code to include it.

Each theme should have a `base.html` file, you should look at that to make sure it's included there.  If not you can add something like:

```html
{% if GOOGLE_ANALYTICS %}
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}}"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '{{GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}}');
</script>
{% endif %}
```